# Why was Kid sailing in Thriller Bark?

Tags: one-piece

At episode 629 and in chapter 700 we could see how Eustass Kid was sailing a smaller version of the Thriller Bark. Since Gekko Moriah has supposedly died, why is Eustass sailing his ship? What is the connection between any of the alliance and Moriah?

Im not completely sure whether this information is canon as the name is not written in the manga, but I doubt Toei didn't confirm such major news with Oda first. So what gives?

[image: enter image description here!]
[image: enter image description here!]
[image: enter image description here!]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those images does not mean Kidd is using Thriller Bark ship.

The message it wants to imply is that Absalom is the one that leaked the information about the pirate alliance Kidd is forming. The name Absa and the Thrillerbark ship hints that it really is Absalom that leaked the information.

Comment: Ow I see... So absalom stealthily got the information and while they are shouting on the island he smoothly sails away like a boss... makes sense. Thanks!